# Help! What's on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, help-center, scope

When people arrive at our site, they'll be directed to /help/on-topic for guidance about what's on-topic here. Said page currently contains basically nothing useful; I can tell you that without even looking at it.

However, we have moderators now, and we can edit that page. So - what should it say?

Propose some possible help center text in an answer. After a while, we'll amalgamate what we can and come up with some content to put in the help center that'll actually *help* when people come to visit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this, adapted from our [question quality guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/1)?:

On-topic:

> - a recommendation for hardware to perform a specific task, or
> - information that will lead to a purchase decision
>
> **Note** that your question must meet quality requirements. Please [read them here](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/1) before posting.

Off-topic:

> - Technical support of any kind
> - Step-by-step instructions for "do-it-yourself" installation

This would also translate nicely to the ask/don't-ask bullet lists on https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour.

Comment: "Product" should be more clearly defined though. "Hardware" will probably do nicely.

Comment: @Adam How does the edit look?

Comment: Looks great. Also, it would be beneficial to broaden the _don'ts_. "Technical support of any kind."