# on-topic meta tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Should we have a tag for requesting if something is [on-topic]?

There are multiple meta posts here asking if things are on-topic...

- [Are batteries on-topic?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/457/2208)
- [Help! What's on-topic here?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325/help-whats-on-topic-here)
- [Laser cutters on topic?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/laser-cutters-on-topic)

To name a few.

Shouldn't there be a tag to categorize them under?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) meta tag is used for questions of topicality.