# Is asking for hardware recommendation to run a software too broad?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, specific-question

Where does [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/930/what-should-be-hardware-configuration-for-android-development) stand in standards of quality for this community?

It has been put on hold as off topic for being too broad.

I differ from the opinion of moderator @ArtOfCode that it is too broad, because it is targeting a specific problem.

[image]

I'd like an opinion from other moderators on the same topic.

Comment: The answers below are very helpful. I would also refer you to **[How to handle questions with too few requirements](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/177/how-to-handle-questions-with-too-few-requirements/186#186)** to help you understand *why* hosting questions that could solicit a virtually *boundless* number of answers is not really how this site was designed to be used.

Comment: @RobertCartaino after all the updates I made I think there should not be boundless number for answers for this problem. I wonder if there is any place on Internet where I can get help on this problem. please check the update.

Comment: In my opinion, this is still a technical support question trying to troubleshoot a performance issue with your current hardware. Saying you might need faster stuff doesn't mitigate that there is still a near-infinite number of answers that could recommend what you ***could*** buy here. The post I linked above talks about how it may be too soon for a site like this if you haven't narrowed it down a ***definitive*** product search. If you're stuck troubleshooting what the problem is with your setup *specifically,* that sounds like a good question for Super User. That is just my opinion.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I have been directed here from SU. this does not fit there as well. Most suitable audience for this question will be from SO but this is way too off topic for there.

Comment: It looks like tech support after all those updates. But it is not. I came here after all my research. It's no more a problem which I can trouble shoot with resources in hand. My intention is to get opinion from people running similar setup.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with ArtOfCode. This question is broad and unclear, for multiple reasons.

---

Your question is this:

> please suggest appropriate hardware configuration to run Android studio with emulators lag free, please recommend graphics as well to run emulators with host GPU.

The rest of the post is telling us what you have, but seems to have little relevance to the actual question. I am reading the following sub-questions that seem to be implied by the quoted text:

- Is my hardware good enough?
- What hardware can I upgrade to get better performance?
- What hardware should I get in a brand new machine?
- I want a GPU specifically, what should I get?

---

Going through each of those:

> Is my hardware good enough?

Maybe? Explain why the hardware you have doesn't work. What symptoms are you experiencing? It's possible this isn't a hardware issue at all. If that is the case, the question is completely off topic here.

> What hardware can I upgrade to get better performance?

The only requirement you've provided is that you need to "run Android studio with emulators lag free". Remember, you are on a *hardware* recommendation site. It's likely that we know more about hardware than your IDE. I am not an Android developer. I have no idea what the quoted text means. Why do you need emulators? It's really not relevant. You've provided a single requirement that is hard to understand. Expand on what you need and make it easier to understand for users that are more focused on hardware and may be developers of other languages.

> What hardware should I get in a brand new machine?

"Lag free" to me, means a faster internet connection. You should focus on that. More seriously, I have no idea if you are asking if you need new hardware or if you want to replace existing components. Clarify your question.

> I want a GPU specifically, what should I get?

You want to run emulators. Great. Which ones? What do they require? Can they run on onboard graphics chips or do you need a dedicated card or set of cards? Again, you ask us to "recommend graphics [...] to run emulators". That is not clear.

---

Your question needs to be clarified. Explain what isn't working. Explain what you want to do. Assume that we are not Android developers. If you are asking about multiple components, it may be a good idea to separate this question in a series of questions. I really have no idea what running Android studio with emulators means, and thus can't tell you if it does depend on all three components or if you just need a graphics card.

Comment: I partly disagree, even if the answer is long in nature as long as it is well summarized or referenced it does not mean that others will not read it and find relevant information, however an unclear is not good.

Comment: "Long" answers are not the problem. A long answer is fine, if it only has to answer a single question. In this case, though, the question covers a variety of topics ranging from "appropriate hardware" (which could be any component) to graphics cards only, to possibly a brand new machine.

Answer (score 6):

I put this question on hold for two primary reasons.

- **Unclear**
  The acceptance requirement set out in the question is "must be able to run Android Studio". Now, *I* don't know what that entails, and I'm sure quite a number of other people here don't either. While we may have *some* users who understand, it's much better if it's understandable to more people.
  **To remedy:** I'd like to see this requirement defined in terms that are more clear to a larger majority of users. What does Android Studio require to run?
- **Too broad**
  The question, as it is, asks for an "appropriate hardware configuration", and this is clarified in the comments to include "RAM, graphics card, and processor". As mentioned in the comments, it's not *at all* easy to provide an answer that covers all of these topics. Now, the close reason I used doesn't *quite* fit the case, but it says what it needs to - the requirements set out are too broad.
  **To remedy:** The question should be split up - one question for each of RAM, processor, and graphics card. These questions can be tagged appropriately, fine-tuned requirements detailed for each one, and the resulting answers will be better.

I'd also just like to make it clear: this is *not* a personal vendetta against you, or your post. I closed the question in line with the [quality standards](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality) we've defined.

Comment: I agree with this. Leaving your requirements to be defined by software, unless given more info, makes the question very broad and difficult to answer.