# Why are my questions getting removed?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange post: [How relevant are sound cards for a gaming PC?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12315/how-relevant-are-sound-cards-for-a-gaming-pc)

I joined this StackExchange a couple weeks ago because I want to buy a new gaming PC and have some questions about which hardware zu choose. Since then, **every** questions I asked was removed by a moderator. One for good reason (too broad) but with the others I really can't see why they wouldn't fit this side.

An example is the question above: It says that the question was removed because it's a technical support request and that this site is meant for pre-purchase recommendations. But that's exactly what my question is about. I even explicitly state that I'm putting togehter a PC. So I would like to know why it got removed.

Comment: i would have liked to see answers on this sound card topic.

Comment: An answer was given before the question got removed. Can't you see it when you click the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a thin line between pre-purchase, and allowing any tech support question because it might help someone buy a product. Your questions are falling into the latter category. Pre-purchase is for when you've *almost* made a decision, but need more information about whether a product fits your requirements or not; it's not for general information about categories of hardware.

This site has a very narrow scope, and only certain kinds of questions work well here; for general or technical advice or support, you're better off asking on more traditional forums (or, possibly, [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), if it's on-topic there).

Some useful things to read: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); [What is Hardware?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware), and [our quality guidelines for questions](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).