# Should questions like this be closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

Recently, we had [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/455/8) about alternatives to the Raspberry Pi. It's answerable by a quick Google search, and by the [requirements for questions](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/186/8) that Robert Cartaino defined, is not specific enough to warrant being a question here yet.

I've voted to close it using the reason Robert defined in the same answer. The question, however, is this:

Should we **close** or just **heavily downvote** questions like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've voted to close it. The initial question was answerable by simply Googling "Raspberry Pi alternatives". The updated question has added specifications that are common to almost every single one of those alternatives.

The question isn't specific enough to be anything other than a list of those alternatives.

The downvotes are up to you, but I don't see the question as showing any research effort at this point.

Answer (score 4):

In this case I recommend closing the question. This will simply be more helpful at the end of the day because it will show that *lack of research* is unfavorable on this site.

But as discussed in my meta thread about how to handle low-quality questions, downvoting at any time whatsoever is really up to you. It'll of course show that the question isn't liked, but it won't directly help with dealing with the question.

Answer (score 1):

"Some alternatives" isn't a good fit for a Q/A.

There's no indication as to why the Raspberry Pi isn't a good fit, so... what is their actual question?